# Java: How do I cast a cloned object to it's original subclass?

Tags: java, casting, clone, cloning

Imagine super class A:

```
public class A {
    private int x;

    A(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

And it's 2 subclasses B and C:

```
public class B extends A{
    private int y = 2;

    B(int x){
        super(x);
    }
}
```

```
public class C extends A{
    private int y = 3;

    B(int x){
        super(x);
    }
}
```

Now imagine a list of objects that all inherit class A. I want to iterate through that list and clone each object and also cast it to it's original subclass (B or C). This is how I tried to do that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
    aList.add(new B(5));
    aList.add(new C(6));

    ArrayList<A> aClones = new ArrayList<A>();

    for(A a : aList) {
        A aNew = new A(a.getX());
        a.getClass().cast(aNew);
        aClones.add(aNew);
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error saying that I can't cast A to B. How am I able to achieve this without knowing up front what subtype of object I'm dealing with? I could do an if-statement inside the for loop for every type of subclass to check if `a` is an instance of that subclass and then simply create a new instance of that particular subclass and clone it that way. However, in my situation there will be many more subclasses than just B and C and many more might come. I don't want the for loop to contain any knowledge about the existing subclasses of A. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in the way you're writing it.

The reason is fairly simple:  `B` and `C` have an **is-a** relationship with `A`, but `A` doesn't share the same **is-a** relationship with either `B` or `C`.

This is chiefly because you're trying to iterate using the superclass to describe everything.

```
for(A a : aList) { }
```

While you're iterating, **you do not have any way of knowing from type inference *alone* what concrete class `A` actually is.**

So this fails, as expected.

```
 a.getClass().cast(aNew);
```

Without **explicitly asking the class what type it is**, you have no way of doing this.

This means that you'll be writing a lot of `instanceof` of statements if you plan to expand upon this.

```
for(A a : aList) {
    if(a instanceof B) {
        B b = new B(a.getX());
        aClones.add(b);
    }
    if(a instanceof C) {
        C c = new C(a.getX());
        aClones.add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thats too bad. I was hoping something like `A newA = a.getClass().newInstance()` would work, but for some reason any alterations I make to newA after that aren't saved?

Comment: @Tipsi:  I suppose I should be honest. I've *never* wanted to do this in Java.  I can't think of a justifiable reason to do this since it's very, very rare that the subclasses would contain more meaningful information that can't be encapsulated into a single object.  The fact that one has to use `instanceof` sticks out like a sore thumb in that, perhaps, this *might* not be the best way to do this, but it's still an option if you insist upon it.  I would encourage you to think about what it is you're really trying to accomplish here.  Perhaps an object mapper would be a better fit.

Comment: Basically a ShapeObject is a super class and all it's subclasses return a Shape. RectangleObject returns a Rectangle etc. The only information that the subclasses have over their superclass is the Shape type. All ShapeObjects have a Properties object that is generated from XML. When you cast a ShapeObject to RectangleObject, all you're doing is letting the object know it should draw a Rectangle from the generated XML Properties, so you're never losing information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
for(A a : aList) {
    A anew;
    if (a.getClass() == A.class) anow = new A(a.getX());
    else if (a.getClass() == B.class) anow = new B(a.getX());
    else if (...
```

}

Comment: Yes, at the end of my question I also talked about this solution. But in this case you need to know about every subclass in the for loop and in my situation it would be better if I don't have to go through every subclass type and do if-statements. But if this is not possible then I guess I'm out of luck! Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should clone it with the constructor of the subclass. 
Otherwise it will be the Type of the super class A which cannot be casted to C or B 
See e.g. reflection: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Or better use the clone function.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method)

That should be much easier.

Comment: Or use the clone function. That could be the easiest was i guess.

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible to create an instance of a subclass without knowing what subclass you're about to instantiate? Of course I know what subclass it is by using .getClass(), but I can't use that to make a new instance? I also tried .getClass().newInstance() but this doesn't seem to have the behavior I expected it to have.

Comment: Also the object I want to clone doesn't have a cloning method.

Comment: In that case if you can write a clone function for the object. I think every java Object has a clone function since it should be extended from java.Object. but you might need to override the clone function ( See https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/01/java-clone-tutorial-part-2-overriding-with-mutable-field-example.html?m=1).

Comment: Reflection should be possibe too, but that would be much more complicated - I think.